# How to commit update to a custom field on the current issue in JIRA postfunction using Groovy with Adapatvist ScriptRunner

Tags: groovy, jira

I have a Groovy script post-function using Adaptavist ScriptRunner in JIRA. In the script, I look if a checkbox choice is marked on the issue. If so, I want to prefill the custom field Project Manager on the Issue with the value John Smith. The checkbox portion of the code works fine and the script runs to completion without error, but the issue itself does not register the update. I put this together from other accepted examples on this site and the web.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue;

IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();
CustomFieldManager cfm=ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager();
CustomField cf2 = cfm.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Project Manager"); 
def usermanager = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager()
def webmgr = usermanager.getUserByName("John Smith")
issue.setCustomFieldValue(cf2, webmgr);
cf2.updateValue(null, issue, new ModifiedValue(issue.getCustomFieldValue(cf2), webmgr),new DefaultIssueChangeHolder()); 
def user = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser()


// issueManager.updateIssue(user, issue, EventDispatchOption.ISSUE_UPDATED, true);
IssueManager.updateIssue(user,issue,EventDispatchOption.DO_NOT_DISPATCH,true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wanted the username versus the formal name.

```
def webmgr = usermanager.getUserByName("johnsmit")
```